# Ubuntu Upstart Error

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, upstart

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and attempting to run services via start,stop, status  and I get the corresponding error below. I've googled around but everything is like 2-3 years old and unanswered.

```
status: Unable to connect to system bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Are you logged in as root?

Answer (score 7):

D'oh, alright I figured it out... dbus isn't installed for some reason although services were working before..? Not sure what happened, anyways `sudo apt-get install dbus` worked.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you just forget run as sudo : sudo service xxxx status .

i faced the same problem . just figured it out .